# Scanning for erased files

Tags: hard-drive, secure-erase

Here's what I want to do:

- Scan for files that have been deleted
- Erase/wipe the hard drive blocks that those files use to reside on

Basically, I'd like to put these blocks through what [Eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie/) does to existing files.  What software can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Eraser can "erase" free space, would that do what you want?

Comment: @Nifle - does it erase all the free space?  I guess that would work, although it might be overkill.

Comment: Yes it does. Overkill it might be, but at least you are sure nothing is overlooked.

Comment: @Nifle - Awesome!  If you want to add an answer, I'll check it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eraser can "erase" all free space.

It might be overkill, but at least you are sure nothing is overlooked.

Comment: @divided - Feel free to "accept" it as correct and/or vote it up.